# Extract only a single directory from tar (in python)

Tags: python, tar

I am working on a project in python in which I need to extract only a subfolder of tar archive not all the files.
I tried to use

```
tar = tarfile.open(tarfile)
tar.extract("dirname", targetdir)
```

But this does not work, it does not extract the given subdirectory also no exception is thrown. I am a beginner in python. 
Also if the above function doesn't work for directories whats the difference between this command and tar.extractfile() ?

Comment: extractfile() doesn't write a file to the disk, it just gives you a python object. extract() writes to the disk.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Building on the second example from the [tarfile module documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/tarfile.html#examples), you could extract the contained sub-folder and all of its contents with something like this:

```
with tarfile.open("sample.tar") as tar:
    subdir_and_files = [
        tarinfo for tarinfo in tar.getmembers()
        if tarinfo.name.startswith("subfolder/")
    ]
    tar.extractall(members=subdir_and_files)
```

This creates a list of the subfolder and its contents, and then uses the recommended `extractall()` method to extract just them. Of course, replace `"subfolder/"` with the actual path (relative to the root of the tar file) of the sub-folder you want to extract.

Answer (score 16):

The other answer will retain the subfolder path, meaning that `subfolder/a/b` will be extracted to `./subfolder/a/b`. To extract a subfolder to the root, so `subfolder/a/b` would be extracted to `./a/b`, you can rewrite the paths with something like this:

```
def members(tf):
    l = len("subfolder/")
    for member in tf.getmembers():
        if member.path.startswith("subfolder/"):
            member.path = member.path[l:]
            yield member

with tarfile.open("sample.tar") as tar:
    tar.extractall(members=members(tar))
```

Comment: Works great. You can also rename the top-level folder with this style by doing `member.path = os.path.join('new_dirname', member.path[l:])`

Comment: Great tip. Having tarfile extracted with every useless subdirectory really bugged me.

Comment: This works great. Unfortunately, I skipped this answer before by only looking at the best answer.

Comment: I will delete it. Sorry. I was hoping for an answer to a very similar issue. By the way, this solution is not working for me. I'm getting an error: [Pyright reportGeneralTypeIssues] [E] Argument of type "Generator[TarInfo, None, None]" cannot be assigned to parameter "members" of type "List[TarInfo] | None" in function "extractall"
    Type "Generator[TarInfo, None, None]" cannot be assigned to type "List[TarInfo] | None" 
    "Generator[TarInfo, None, None]" is incompatible with "List[TarInfo]"
    Cannot assign to "None"

Comment: Easier to open a new question than leaving a comment with not enough information. The code works correctly if you run it in Python. The error you're showing is a static typing error, not something that will stop the code from functioning. Fix for that error: https://github.com/python/typeshed/pull/5273