# Python read file within tar archive

Tags: python, tar

I have a file:"docs.tar.gz".The tar file has 4 files inside of which the fourth file is "docs.json" which is what I need.Im able to view the contents of the tar file using:

```
import tarfile
tar=tarfile.open("docs.tar.gz")
tar.getmembers()
```

How would I read the fourth file -the json file that I need?..Im unable to proceed after extracting the contents.Thanks!

Comment: Mayby this [anwser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8008829/extract-only-a-single-directory-from-tar) will be useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
import tarfile
tar = tarfile.open("docs.tar.gz")
f = tar.extractfile("docs.json")

# do something like f.read()
# since your file is json, you'll probably want to do this:

import json
json.loads(f.read())
```

Comment: a little comment that it's not a good practice to create variable with the name `file`, it's taken by Python

Comment: File "/usr/lib/python2.7/gzip.py", line 312, in _read
    uncompress = self.decompress.decompress(buf)
error: Error -3 while decompressing: invalid literal/length code

This is the error I get though when i read the json file

Comment: Looks like a corrupt file @ashwinshanker

Comment: @ nathancahill..Looks like the file was too big to open-thanks anyway!

Answer (score 5):

This one will work too.

```
import tarfile
tar = tarfile.open("docs.tar.gz")
files = tar.getmembers()
f = tar.extractfile(files[0]) # if your docs.json is in the 0th position
f.readlines()
```

Answer (score 0):

As an example using Python3's context managers, a JSON file like this:

```
$ cat myfile.json
{
    "key1": 1,
    "key2": 2,
    "key3": null
}
```

is compressed with

```
tar czvf myfile.json.tar.gz myfile.json
```

and can be extracted like this

```
import tarfile
import json

tar_file_name = "myfile.json.tar.gz"
data_file_name = "myfile.json"
with tarfile.open(tar_file_name, "r:gz") as tar:
    with tar.extractfile(data_file_name) as f:
        j = json.loads(f.read())

print(j)
# {'key1': 1, 'key2': 2, 'key3': None}
```