# Equivalent functionality of tar --strip in python tarfile, for randomly named subfolder

Tags: python, tarfile

I have several tar files with the following directory structure: `a/b/c/xyz.txt`

I want to extract the files from these tar files by ignoring the parent directory `'a'`. After extraction, I am expecting the following directory structure: `b/c/xyz.txt`

With tar command, we can use `--strip=1` option.

Now this has been asked before in [Equivalent functionality of tar --strip in python tarfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65765636/equivalent-functionality-of-tar-strip-in-python-tarfile) for one tar file with a clearly named directory `'a'`, but I've got an extra issue.

The directory `'a'` of tarfile `'A'` is named `'projectname-1d30420'`, for tarfile `'B'` it's `'differentprojectname-ed1d5db'` and so on for `'C'` to `'Z'`.

How to do this using tarfile in python?

Comment: if you have path `something/a/b` then you can always use `path.split('/', 1)[1]` to get only `a/b`

Comment: you could even write it as `path.split('/', strip)[-1]`

Answer (score 3):

If you have path `a/b/c` then you can split it on first `/` and get last element to get `b/c`

```
path = path.split('/', 1)[-1]
```

You can even use variable to get the same result like with `--strip`

```
strip = 1  # 2, 3, etc.

path = path.split('/', strip)[-1]
```

---

Based on code from your link but I did't test it

```
def members(tar, strip):
    for member in tar.getmembers():
        member.path = member.path.split('/', strip)[-1]
        yield member

# --- main ---

strip = 1

with tarfile.open("sample.tar") as tar:
    tar.extractall(members=members(tar, strip))
```

Answer (score 2):

I've figured it out.
The member files in tar.extractall can have their extraction paths stripped using the pathlib library like so `member.path = p.relative_to(*p.parts[:strip])` where `p = Path(member.path)` and `strip` is the number of folders stripped.

This results in the following code:

```
import tarfile
from pathlib import Path

def get_tar_members_stripped(tar, n_folders_stripped = 1):
    members = []
    for member in tar.getmembers():
        p = Path(member.path)
        member.path = p.relative_to(*p.parts[:n_folders_stripped])
        members.append(member)
    return members

# --- main ---

strip = 1

with tarfile.open(tarfile_path, 'r') as tar:
 tar.extractall(members=get_tar_members_stripped(tar, strip))
```