# Python tarfile.extract func not extracting content of directory

Tags: python, linux, tarfile

I'm trying to extract a directory from tarfile using python. But some/ALL of its files inside that directory are missing after extraction. Only pathname got extracted (ie, I get folder home inside /tmp/myfolder but its empty)

Code is as follwing:

```
for tar in tarfiles:
    mytar = tarfile.open(tar)
    for file in mytar:
         if file == "myfile":
               mytar.extract('home', /tmp/myfolder)
```

Comment: Never name variables the same as modules, they are overwritten. for tar in tarfiles: . And extractall() use.

Comment: Right.  You did `open(tarfile)`, so you should have `for tarfile in tarfiles:`.

Comment: Extract the file you found, not `"home"` - `mytar.extract(file, /tmp/myfolder)`. Add some prints for when you find the file and when the `for` doesn't find anything (thus no write). And there is no need to scan all of the files if you are extracting a known file name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a fix, by default extract only extracts path of variable, I can get content with

```
tar.extractall(members=members(tar))
```

Reference:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/43094365/20223973